# Can't leave organization I'm not an admin of

Tags: azure-devops

I am a member of an organization I am not the admin of. I can't seem to find a way to leave.

I don't know who is the admin. It seems to be a long deceased project/organization where I was once added as a member. Now I can't get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Go My profile, open the org which you are the member is and want to leave. Then you will see a button **Leave** in the right panel.

Click that, you will **delete yourself from the organization will remove your permissions permanently** and this don't need the admin's allow or contact with org's admin.

[image]

[image]